# Is guaranteed in Spring that int values of TransactionDefinition and Propagation are always same?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I would like to work with `DefaultTransactionDefinition` and create it using a custom method.

```
public DefaultTransactionDefinition definition(int timeout, int propagationBehavior) {
    final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(...);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(propagationBehavior);
    transactionTemplate.setTimeout(timeoutSeconds);
    ...
    return transactionTemplate;
}
```

The API [suggests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/DefaultTransactionDefinition.html) using `TransactionDefinition` interface to represent the propagation behavior:

> Default implementation of the TransactionDefinition interface, offering bean-style configuration and sensible default values (PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_DEFAULT, TIMEOUT_DEFAULT, readOnly=false).

```
public interface TransactionDefinition {

    int PROPAGATION_REQUIRED = 0;
    int PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS = 1;
    int PROPAGATION_MANDATORY = 2;
    int PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW = 3;
    ...
```

With all respect to the creators, one has to be really wasted to define *"sensible"* values as `int` in an interface. The code becomes error-prone:

```
// BOOM: both compile but the latter is completely wrong
DefaultTransactionDefinition d1 = definition(3000, TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
DefaultTransactionDefinition d2 = definition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, 3000);
```

Keep reading: I would like to overcome this issue using the `Propagation` instead which is a proper `enum`:

```
public enum Propagation {
    REQUIRED(0),
    SUPPORTS(1),
    MANDATORY(2),
    REQUIRES_NEW(3),
    ...
```

```
public DefaultTransactionDefinition definition(int timeout, Propagation propagation) {
    final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(...);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(propagation.value());
    transactionTemplate.setTimeout(timeoutSeconds);
    ...
    return transactionTemplate;
}
```

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition d1 = definition(3000, Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW);
DefaultTransactionDefinition d2 = definition(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, 3000); // correctly doesn't compile
```

Although, the `Propagation` class is in the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation` package suggests this shall be used only for the `@Transactional` annotation, I can close my eyes and pretend it is ok.

**Now the question:**

As long as there is no reference between `TransactionDefinition` and `Propagation`, how can I be assured that the integer `3` always represents the propagation `REQUIRE_NEW` etc? These two classes are completely disconnected and duplicate code.

I have trust issues: is there any reference to the documentation explaining the usage of both classes and whether these "constants" respect each other?

Comment: The docs of [`Propagation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) says: _"Enumeration that represents transaction propagation behaviors for use with the Transactional annotation, corresponding to the [`TransactionDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html) interface."_, so yes, you can expect this to work as it is documented to correspond.

Comment: Also, the actual [source code of `Propagation`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.java) uses the constants of `TransactionDefinition`. You may want to configure your IDE to download sources.

Comment: Excellent. I didn't bother to check the documentation of `Propagation` because there is no relationship in the `Propagation` source code, such as `REQUIRED(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED)`.

Comment: That relationship is there in the source code (see link above), likely you looked at sources decompiled by your IDE, instead of the actual sources

Comment: You are right, IntelliJ Idea confused me once again. Thanks a lot! Post the answer, I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`Propagation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) says:

> Enumeration that represents transaction propagation behaviors for use
> with the Transactional annotation, corresponding to the
> [`TransactionDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html) interface.

So, yes, you can expect this to work as it is documented to correspond.

In addition, the [actual source code of `Propagation`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.java) uses the constants of `TransactionDefinition`:

```java
public enum Propagation {

    /**
     * Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.
     * Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.
     * <p>This is the default setting of a transaction annotation.
     */
    REQUIRED(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED),
```